# Add multiple payment options in Google Product feed XML

Tags: google, xml, affiliate

In my Google Product feed I have both Visa and MasterCard listed as accepted payment methods. Is it possible, and is there any benefit, in adding the remainder of my payment options; American Express, Delta, Maestro etc.

```
        <g:payment_accepted>Visa</g:payment_accepted>
        <g:payment_accepted>MasterCard</g:payment_accepted>
```

I can't find anything in the specification that mentions the payment methods.

My feed applies to the UK, US and EU.

Comment: If there is ANY benefit to ranking it likely is small. Google just wants to help themselves to your data. Always remember that.

Comment: @unixman83 I am providing my data _to_ Google, though. There is significant commercial benefit to providing a feed of products to Google. Visa and MasterCard are both accepted, however, for the sake of completeness i'd like to add all payment types. But, as you say, there may be limited benefit in terms of ranking.

Comment: I haven't found any documentation that states what the accepted methods are, or if there is any actual benefit in specifying all payment methods as yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that there are little to no ranking benefits from adding a bunch of extra payment options to the `<g:payment_accepted>` node.